# Link mysql to application in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi how would I connect a mysql container to another container so that my application in one of those container can use Mysql? Based on this [reference](https://docs.docker.com/samples/mysql/) I need to run this

```
docker run --name some-app --link some-mysql:mysql -d application-that-uses-mysql
```

But I have no idea what does some-app mean and the application-that-uses-mysql? does it mean the container ID that will use it? below is the list of the running container

[image]

Comment: Why don't you save yourself a lot of hassle and just use docker-compose?

Answer (score 2):

`--name some-app` refers to the container name you want to assign to the container you are running.

`application-that-uses-mysql` refers to the image which you are using. This image requires `mysql` and you have connecte myqsl to this image by using the command `--link some-mysql:mysql`.

However, Links are deprecated but you still can connect to other containers using networks. An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197727/6207775) should be able to help you out in setting the connections.

Edit: Removed duplicate and provided complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

`--name some-app` gives the newly started container the name `some-app`.

`--link some-mysql:mysql` links the container with name `some-mysql` (this is the one running MySQL) to the new container so that it can be accessed as `mysql`within the container.

`application-that-uses-mysql`is the name of the image containing your app.

If you are unsure about the meaning of some parameters, there is always the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).